# Can a kafka client to play multiple role both consumer and producer

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've created a scenario at which a client which has Producer role publishes a message in topic in the kafka cluster and a client which has Consumer role  subscribes in this topic and polls the message from the log. My question is if the client which has Consumer role   after this make also a process for example (database processing) and he want to send some data back,then it must take producer role and the other client from his previous producer role become a consumer. Is it feasible a client can to be able to play both the consumer-producer role? Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. There is no reason why you should not be able to instantiate a consumer and a producer in the same client. You might want to check out [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#streams), that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Can y give me an Example?

Comment: Just instantiate a https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html and a https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html and you are done. :)

Comment: And it is possible to dispatch message to some topic from consumer while subscribing to other topic? I like to apply sagas pattern to simulate rollback transaction, but I can't understand how I can produce new message to another topic without requesting some API endpoint... (using  Nest.js on top of kafkjas just in case)
Producer send message to topic -> Consumer subscribe to topic -> Again Produce new message to topic-> etc...

Comment: Not sure if I understand what the exact problem is? Maybe start a new question? What do you mean by `without requesting some API endpoint` ?

Comment: How I can chain multiple commands / events, after I dispatch the first event? If I produce some event / topic, consumer is subscring to it, do some operations, next, how I can continue to dispatch new events? I'm talking particular about sagas pattern

Comment: I am not familiar with the sagas pattern. -- Still not sure if I fully understand what you want to do, but in Kafka Streams you can use the Processor API to emit as many output event per into event as you like, by calling `context.forward()` as many times as you like. There are also punctuation that allow you to invoke a call-back regularly to sent events downstream. For the DSL, you could use `flatMap()` to "split" a single input event into multiple. -- Again: please start a new question...